# How to implement vertex skinning with cocos3D

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I need to implement vertex skinning of a body using skeletal animation.
My project is written in cocos2D, so the solution, i've chosen is to use cocos3D and vertex skinning.
I looked into the examples in cocos 0.6.5 archive, but example shows only how to load animation from POD file.
Instead of this I want to construct skeleton manually, create CCSkinMeshNode and animate it using my own algorithms(without building 3D model in 3D-editors).

I googled it, but couldn't find any documentation or examples that describe how to work with skeleton, bones in cocos3d.

Or may be i should try to use OpenGL code?